# On search multiple selected are not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

With the below code I am able to do Multiple select and search, but every time I search selected rows does not have check image, but in selProjArr I have those selected data. selProjArr is like this.

```
{
    "projectName" : "ITP 10",
    "projectId" : 91,
    "projectImage" : null
}
```

TableviewCell

```
class FilterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var projImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var projName: UILabel!
    // MARK: - variable Declaration
    var isChecked = Bool()
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Background
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "check box"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "check box1"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

```
var projDropDownArr = NSArray()
var projDropDict = NSDictionary()
var selProjDict = NSDictionary()
var selProjArr = NSMutableArray()
var projFilArr = NSArray()
```

```
extension FilterVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if projFilArr.count > 0 {
            return self.projFilArr.count
        } else {
            return self.projDropDownArr.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
        //OnSearch
        if projFilArr.count > 0 {
            self.projDropDict = self.projFilArr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
            let stringPoj = self.projDropDict["projectName"] as? String
            cell.projName.text = stringPoj
            let stringPojImage = self.projDropDict["projectImage"] as? String
            let imageUrl = stringPojImage ?? ""
            if imageUrl != "" {
                let url = URL(string: stringPojImage!)
                cell.projImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                cell.projImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            } else {
                cell.projImage.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultprojectIcon")
            }
        } else {
            self.projDropDict = self.projDropDownArr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
            let stringPoj = self.projDropDict["projectName"] as? String
            cell.projName.text = stringPoj
            let stringPojImage = self.projDropDict["projectImage"] as? String
            let imageUrl = stringPojImage ?? ""
            if imageUrl != "" {
                let url = URL(string: stringPojImage!)
                cell.projImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                cell.projImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            } else {
                cell.projImage.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultprojectIcon")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    //Removing selected from selProjArr
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)
        self.projDropDict = self.projDropDownArr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        selProjArr.removeObject(identicalTo: self.projDropDict)
        print(selProjArr)
    }
    //Adding selected to selProjArr
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
        self.projDropDict = self.projDropDownArr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        selProjArr.add(self.projDropDict)
        print(selProjArr)
    }
    // This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print("Serach Text : ", searchText)
        let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "projectName contains[c] %@", searchText)
        let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [firstNamePredicate])
        let filteredArray = projDropDownArr.filter { compoundPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
        projFilArr = NSArray(array: filteredArray)
        print("searched array  = \(projFilArr)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.projectTblView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

No I am not using model/struct/codable,
I am new to this swift any help is appreciated. If you want the full code let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `NSArray()` & `NSDictionary()`? In Swift you can simply declare arrays as `[String]` and dictionaries as `[String: String]`. It's better that way because it doesn't require all this casting you're constantly doing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.